# How to create SOAP messages ? How to convert a soap message to an object?

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap, wsdl

1- How do i create soap messages to communicate with a web service? Let's say my client needs to send a request to a web service, Do i generate the FULL soap string and then send it to the web service, including header, body, envelop etc?

2- Let's say the web service sends me back a SOAP response, the response contains information about 4 different users info in my database?
How do i convert the soap message to 4 "objects of User"?
Do i need to loop through the message and read each parameter 1 by 1, and create my "User" objects? or is there an easier way of matching the parameters in the soap message with parameters in my class and create the objects automatically?

Comment: Any specific language for your client?

Comment: Well my client is iphone, but the question is a general question, I'm trying to learn and understand how soap and web service communication work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [`WSDL`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) of that [`webservice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), many [`IDE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)'s have the ability to import the [`WSDL`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) and auto generate a client program for the bindings.

So, if the [`webservice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) returns many `USER` objects, your [`IDE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)' will *generate* them back. If not, it will generate `objects` for the kind of response your [`webservice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) returns.

With those `objects`, i think will be easier to extract the `users` from it than from the raw `envelope`